# Push/Pop items from observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

My requirement is to show list of `Employee`s with CRUD operations. 
So I have created a HTML which subscribes an `employee$` observable with `async` pipe to show all employee details.

Now for create employee option, i need to add a new row to employee$ observable & for delete employee, i need to remove one value from that.

Here comes the question. I need an observable in which i can add/remove/modify the values when needed. There were suggestions  to use `BehaviourSubject` instead of `Observable` but i can only add things to it. I cannot remove anything from it ( for Delete i need to remove one from it).

Another option is to just subscribe the observable in the component and use the array directly instead of using `async` pipe which i do not want to do.

Is there any way out there to make CRUD operation in an Observable Array?

Comment: if you are using `behaviour-subject` you can use `next` method to push states into. If I'm understanding your question correctly are you looking for something related to `state-management`?

Comment: You don't want to remove something from the observable. You want to emit a new value which is an array with an item less. You're confusing you data structures here.

Answer (score 0):

I reckon [scan](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/scan.html) is a good bet:

```
type Command = {op: 'add', employee: Employee}|{op: 'remove', id: number}|{op: 'update', employee: Employee};

const commandSubject = new Subject<Command>();

const employees$ = commandSubject.scan((acc: Employee[], curr: Command) => {
  switch(curr.op) {
    case 'add':
      return [...acc, curr.employee];
    case 'remove':
      const newList = [...acc];
      newList.splice(acc.findIndex(employee => employee.id = curr.employeeId), 1);
      return newList;
    case 'update':
      const newList2 = [...acc];
      newList2.splice(acc.findIndex(employee => employee.id = curr.employee.id), 1, curr.employee);
      return newList2;
  }
}, []);
```

Also note that [ngrx-store](https://github.com/ngrx/store) is a great tool for managing application state.